# Having problems with importing a module

Tags: python, python-import, pythonpath

I use `os.chdir()` to change the current directory where my recommendations.py file is. 
Then I type `Import recommendations` and I get error:

```
ImportError: No module named recommendations.
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Python only looks in the *initial* working directory (and a few other places) by default. If you change the current directory, insert the new working directory into the search path:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't use the current working directory to import modules, except insofar as it adds the initial directory to the path when starting up. You need to add the directory to your Python path, either by setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or by modifying `sys.path`.